# Get the latest data comparing datetime fields from two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables with identical structure like this:

Table : **user**

```
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
| ID | Name   |    Password  |    LastUpdateTime    |
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
|  1 | abu    |    abu123NEW |  2014-06-04 14:55:06 |
|  2 | john   |      john123 |  2014-06-04 14:58:22 |
|  3 | shane  |     shane123 |  2014-06-04 15:02:06 |
|  4 | marie  |     marie123 |  2014-06-04 15:00:06 |
|  5 | mike   |   mike123NEW |  2014-06-04 15:01:32 |
|  6 | kiron  |  kiron123NEW |  2014-06-04 15:05:46 |
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
```

Table : **user_k**

```
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
| ID | Name   |    Password  |    LastUpdateTime    |
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
|  1 | abu    |       abu123 |  2014-06-04 14:53:06 |
|  2 | john   |   john123NEW |  2014-06-04 14:59:48 |
|  3 | shane  |  shane123NEW |  2014-06-04 15:00:06 |
|  4 | marie  |  marie123NEW |  2014-06-04 15:03:17 |
|  5 | mike   |      mike123 |  2014-06-04 15:00:36 |
|  6 | kiron  |     kiron123 |  2014-06-04 15:02:18 |
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
```

Now I need to fetch the latest data (by 'LastUpdateTime') from these two tables, like this:

```
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
| ID | Name   |    Password  |    LastUpdateTime    |
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
|  1 | abu    |    abu123NEW |  2014-06-04 14:55:06 |
|  2 | john   |   john123NEW |  2014-06-04 14:59:48 |
|  3 | shane  |     shane123 |  2014-06-04 15:02:06 |
|  4 | marie  |  marie123NEW |  2014-06-04 15:03:17 |
|  5 | mike   |   mike123NEW |  2014-06-04 15:01:32 |
|  6 | kiron  |  kiron123NEW |  2014-06-04 15:05:46 |
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
```

What I have tried:

```
SELECT uk.* FROM user AS ua, user_k AS uk
WHERE  uk.ID = ua.ID AND uk.LastUpdateTime > ua.LastUpdateTime

UNION

SELECT ua.* FROM user AS ua ,user_k AS uk
WHERE  uk.ID = ua.ID AND uk.LastUpdateTime < ua.LastUpdateTime
```

I'm not sure if this is the appropriate way. Also I'm concerned about the query performance with large set of data. Is there any better approach for this?

**PS**: *Besides name & password there are a dozen more fields(columns) in both tables. I avoid them just to simplify the question.*

Comment: You need to make a optimized `UNION` between your two tables, but ordered by `LastUpdateTime` ?

Comment: @Kabulan0lak.. Yes I need the latest data but not sure whether UNION is the best in this case..

Comment: Why not ? I think using a `UNION ALL` in this case would be fast and clean.

Comment: OOh sorry, I didn't realize the users in the two tables were the same. `UNION` in very wrong therefore, yep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
u.id,
u.name,
if(u.LastUpdateTime >= k.LastUpdateTime, u.password, k.password) as password,
greatest(u.LastUpdateTime, k.LastUpdateTime) as LastUpdateTime
from
user u
inner join user_k k on u.id = k.id
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14cc4e/4/0)</kbd>

P.S.: *For id 3 the newer password is actually the one from user table, not user_k. Your desired result set needs this adjustment.*

Comment: Nope, this will not return the correct password as the user stipulated.

Comment: @fancyPants Thanks for for answer.. :) However, besides name & password there are a dozen more columns in both tables.. So do I have to make the `if()` comparison for each column..? Also, what about the performance compared to `UNION` method i mentioned in question..?

Comment: Yes, you have to make the if() comparison for each column. I'm absolutely sure, that UNION performance will be much worse.