# Get the latest data by datetime fields from two tables

Tags: mysql, join

This question is slightly different from my previous question :  [Get the latest data comparing datetime fields from two table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077527/get-the-latest-data-comparing-datetime-fields-from-two-tables)

I have two tables with identical structure like this:

Table : **user**

```
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
| ID | Name   |    Password  |    LastUpdateTime    |
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
|  1 | abu    |    abu123NEW |  2014-06-04 14:55:06 |
|  2 | john   |      john123 |  2014-06-04 14:58:22 |
|  3 | shane  |     shane123 |  2014-06-04 15:02:06 |
|  4 | marie  |     marie123 |  2014-06-04 15:00:06 |
|  5 | mike   |   mike123NEW |  2014-06-04 15:01:32 |
|  6 | kiron  |  kiron123NEW |  2014-06-04 15:05:46 |
|  8 | Bruce  |     bruce123 |  2014-06-04 15:07:11 |
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
```

Table : **user_k**

```
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
| ID | Name   |    Password  |    LastUpdateTime    |
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
|  1 | abu    |       abu123 |  2014-06-04 14:53:06 |
|  2 | john   |   john123NEW |  2014-06-04 14:59:48 |
|  3 | shane  |  shane123NEW |  2014-06-04 15:00:06 |
|  4 | marie  |  marie123NEW |  2014-06-04 15:03:17 |
|  5 | mike   |      mike123 |  2014-06-04 15:00:36 |
|  6 | kiron  |     kiron123 |  2014-06-04 15:02:18 |
|  7 | Dan    |       dan123 |  2014-06-04 15:09:46 |
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
```

Now I need to fetch the latest data (by 'LastUpdateTime') from these two tables, like this:

```
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
| ID | Name   |    Password  |    LastUpdateTime    |
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
|  1 | abu    |    abu123NEW |  2014-06-04 14:55:06 |
|  2 | john   |   john123NEW |  2014-06-04 14:59:48 |
|  3 | shane  |     shane123 |  2014-06-04 15:02:06 |
|  4 | marie  |  marie123NEW |  2014-06-04 15:03:17 |
|  5 | mike   |   mike123NEW |  2014-06-04 15:01:32 |
|  6 | kiron  |  kiron123NEW |  2014-06-04 15:05:46 |
|  7 | Dan    |       dan123 |  2014-06-04 15:09:46 |
|  8 | Bruce  |     bruce123 |  2014-06-04 15:07:11 |
+----+--------+--------------+----------------------+
```

What I have now:

```
select
u.id,
u.name,
if(u.LastUpdateTime >= k.LastUpdateTime, u.password, k.password) as password,
greatest(u.LastUpdateTime, k.LastUpdateTime) as LastUpdateTime
from
user u
inner join user_k k on u.id = k.id
```

But this fetches only those records that are available with both tables...
I need the data that is present in any one table of the tables also. Also, I'm concerned about the query performance with large set of data.

**Here is the <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05d8be/1)</kbd>**

**PS**: *Besides name & password there are a dozen more fields(columns) in both tables. I avoid them just to simplify the question.*

Comment: What would the dersired result look like, and (while it's entirely up to you) I do wish you'd provide proper DDLs, and/or an sqlfiddle - without the unnecessary columns.

Comment: @Strawberry : I've added a sample sqlfiddle to my question... :)

Comment: So, you want the latest row for each id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one solution:

```
SELECT * from 

(SELECT u.*
FROM user u LEFT OUTER JOIN user_k uk ON u.ID = uk.ID WHERE 
(uk.ID IS NULL OR u.LastUpdateTime > uk.LastUpdateTime)

UNION ALL

SELECT uk.*
FROM user_k uk LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON u.ID = uk.ID WHERE 
(u.ID IS NULL OR uk.LastUpdateTime >= u.LastUpdateTime)) usr

order by usr.ID
```

<kbd>**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05d8be/22)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * FROM user
       UNION ALL
       SELECT * FROM user_k
     ) x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id,MAX(lastupdatetime) max_lut
         FROM
            ( SELECT * FROM user
               UNION ALL
              SELECT * FROM user_k
            ) a
        GROUP
           BY id
     ) y
    ON y.id = x.id
   AND y.max_lut = x.lastupdatetime
 ORDER
    BY id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05d8be/14